# Getting "not a properly formatted private key" when adding nodes using OpsCenter LCM

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Environment
Opscenter6.8
RHEL8 on GCP

When building a new cluster in Opscenter's "Lifecycle Manager", after adding a node and starting the installation, I get

"The ssh-private-key value on machine-credential 'user-name' is not a property formatted private key"

is displayed.

I have already added the user and set up the password and private key in RHEL8, and I can make SSH connection from Opscenter server to the node.

Is there any possible cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the configuration details and the full error message in the logs, the most likely cause of the issue you're seeing is that there was a mistake in the cut-and-paste when you [added the private key in the LCM web UI](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.8/opsc/LCM/opscLCMaddSshCreds.html).

Check the private key again from the source and compare it with what you have added to LCM and [replace the saved private key](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.8/opsc/LCM/opscLCMeditSshCreds.html) as appropriate.

If that still doesn't work, I would follow Madhavan's advice and log a ticket with [DataStax Support](https://support.datastax.com). Cheers!

Comment: As per your answer, the cut and paste of the private key was not working.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Not a problem. I'm glad you sorted it out. Cheers!